# How to get Battle.net working on Elementary OS 0.4.1?

Tags: software-installation, elementary-os, wine

I have followed both these guides to install Wine and Battle.net on my Elementary OS system, with configuration -

- Elementary OS 0.4.1 (Loki) [Built on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS]
- 8GB RAM
- Intel Core i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz

Guide 1 - https://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft/comments/5w0wyv/how_to_play_sc2_on_linux_a_full_walk_through/

Guide 2 - https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-blizzard-battle-net-app-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

All goes well until I reach the step where I have to install Battle.net through Wine. I've tried this using both the different commands in these guides -

`$ wine64 ~/Downloads/Battle.net-Setup.exe`

and

`$ WINEARCH=win32 vblank_mode=0 Downloads/Battle.net-Setup.exe`

but they both lead to the same error window -

`The program Battle.net-Setup.exe has encountered a serious problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience.`

Answer (score 0):

You're best solution is to use PlayOnLinux. It's an automatic wine cdonfiguration tool mostly for games but for other Windows common application too. It has a strong community that maintains compatibility script to configure wine the best possible way.

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_precise.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Once installed start PlayOnLinux, select install and select the Blizzard game you want to select.
Provide the exe of the game you've download on Internet and it should work.
Most of blizzard game work almost perfect on Wine you can check on the site :
https://www.playonlinux.com/en/supported_apps-1-0.html

Source: 
[PlayOnLinux on Elementary OS](http://www.elementaryos-fr.org/documentation/wine/wine-playonlinux/)

Comment: I was a bit reluctant to use PlayOnLinux because of the dodgy reviews for Blizzard games. Finally, I got Wine working on my system using the instructions on this thread - https://askubuntu.com/questions/846651/installing-starcraft-2-playonlinux